# CSS centering image over image

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hello I'm having an issue to center an image on another image so it would work event when resizing window..
Currently I've made it centered on bigger screen sizes, but when it's resized to smaller it doesn't stay centered...
See below screens and code.

[image: On bigger screen looks goods]

[image: When screen is resized it doesn't keep centered]

Here is the code.
for HTML I'm using bootstrap 3 Thumbnails component:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="images/stone-1.png" id="stone-1" alt="Stone 1 | AmberCRO">
            <img src="images/notebook-streamline.png" id="s-pic-hover-1" class="s-pic-over" alt="AmberCRO">
            <div class="caption service-1">
                <h3>Preparation</h3>
                <p>I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS currently

```css
.thumbnail  {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;      
    border: 0 none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.s-pic-over  {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 142px;
}
```

What can I do so the book image would always stay centered at stone image on all the window sizes?

Comment: Looks like you need to specifically declare the `position` of `.thumbnail`  `relative`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to set `position: relative` to `.thumbnail` , otherwise, `.s.pic-over` will be `absolute` to first parent in DOM, in this case `html`, that's why it is not good in every breakpoints

```css
.thumbnail {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0 none;
  box-shadow: none;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}
.s-pic-over {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="//placehold.it/300x300" id="stone-1" alt="Stone 1 | AmberCRO">
        <img src="//lorempixel.com/100/100" id="s-pic-hover-1" class="s-pic-over" alt="AmberCRO">
        <div class="caption service-1">
          <h3>Preparation</h3>
          <p>I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my proposal:

```
.thumbnail {
 text-align:center;
 }
 #image-container
 {
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 height:300px;
 }
 #stone-1
 { 
 position:absolute;
 z-index:10;
 margin:auto;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 }
 #s-pic-hover-1{
 z-index:9;
 position:absolute;
 margin:auto; 
 left: 0;
 right:0;
 }
```

I used an image container div.

```
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
           <div id="image-container">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" id="s-pic-hover-1" alt="Stone 1 | AmberCRO">
              <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" id="stone-1" class="s-pic-over" alt="AmberCRO">
           </div>
           <div class="caption service-1">
              <h3>Preparation</h3>
              <p>I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine.</p>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Your idea with additional container gave me some good thoughts. It works as well!